# Can you stop a jframe's title bar from resizing the jframe without removing it?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

[This is a picture of the jframe in the design view vs when I'm actually running it.  The title bar causes some components to be cut out of the frame.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ve3bd.png)

Is there any way to fix this without removing the title bar?
I'm using "Null Layout" on my frame.

Comment: can you add the example code here ?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try adding this code into your constructor just below the `initcomponents()` method:

```
setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

If this doesn't work, please update your answer with the code.

Comment: Thank you for Accepting this as an answer. Please upvote if this helped.

Comment: *"Please upvote if this helped."* It didn't, so I down voted. Really, what you are suggesting is a hack for code that should be fixed. See my point (2) above for how.